# spring boot security jwt access additional information in controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth, jwt

I'm currently using OAuth with the password grant type to manage the security of my Spring Boot application. Now I want to store a login id which is queried by the auth server from the database when the client has successfully requested an access token.

To realize this I thought of passing it with the JWT. I used a custom TokenEnhancer in combination with a TokenChain to add the additional login id, which works fine. My problem is that I couldn't find a way, other than parsing the token myself, to get that login id.

Another, but a very bad solution could be to just pass it as authority.

Comment: Since the JWT is signed and encoded, you would need to parse the token yourself. Thankfully, the middle section of a JWT is just a Base64 encoded string representation of the claims you've embedded. So Base64.getDecoder().decode(jwtString.split(".")[1]) should get you the claims that you can then transform into a HashMap<String, Object>. The other option is using a library like JJWT. Or, if you go the "granted authorities" route, check out https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-principal-authorities-extractor

Comment: Thank you, I used granted authorities and everything works now.